# Failed to call gfprimfd() in MATLAB R2012b

Tags: matlab, sequence

I wish to use this function whose documentation can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gfprimfd.html). However, there seems to be no such function in my MATLAB.

```
>> help gfprimfd

gfprimfd not found.

Use the Help browser search field to search the documentation, or
type "help help" for help command options, such as help for methods.
```

Then, I noticed that the documentation actually writes "R2014a".

Does that mean the function is not included in my R2012b version? Besides installing a R2014a version, what can I do to use this function?

## Update

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
MATLAB License Number: 724504
Operating System: Mac OS X  Version: 10.9.2 Build: 13C64 
Java Version: Java 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Simulink                                              Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.2        (R2012b)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 5.1        (R2012b)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.3        (R2012b)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 8.3        (R2012b)
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox                                   Version 2.2.16     (R2012b)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 3.2.2      (R2012b)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 8.1        (R2012b)
MATLAB Compiler                                       Version 4.18       (R2012b)
MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 3.13       (R2012b)
Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 3.6        (R2012b)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 6.2.1      (R2012b)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.1        (R2012b)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.18       (R2012b)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 8.1        (R2012b)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 8.1        (R2012b)
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 4.10       (R2012b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the [Communications System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/communications/).  See the output of `ver`.

Comment: seems to be true.. Please see the update. In such a case do I need to pay extra money to buy the toolkit?

Comment: Yes, but you can get a trial from that page.  Sorry.